# Maximum Distinct code failing hidden test scenarios

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

I was given a hackerrank problem, while my solution worked for the provided sample scenarios, it failed for several `hidden` test cases.

Would the community have an input on possible flaws in my code and thinking process?

**Problem:**
Suppose we have two arrays array1, array2, we want to replace the elements in array1 with elements in array2, so array1 can have the maximum number of distinct elements. The number of replacements is specified as an input parameter.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args){
        var array1=new int[]{2, 3, 3, 2, 2}; 
var array2=new int[]{1, 3, 2, 4, 1};
        int noOfElements=array1.Length; int maxElementsToBeReplaced=2;
        var result=MaximumDistinctElements(array1, array2, noOfElements, maxElementsToBeReplaced);
    }   
    public static int MaximumDistinctElements(int[] array1, int[] array2, int noOfElements, int maxElementsToBeReplaced){
        if (array1.Distinct().Count() == array1.Count())
        {
            return array1.Count();
        }
        var dictionary=array1.GroupBy(x=>x).ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, y=>y.Count());
        while(maxElementsToBeReplaced>0){
            for(var i=0; i<array2.Length; i++)
            {
                if(!dictionary.ContainsKey(array2[i])) 
                {
                    var FirstOrDefault=dictionary.Where(x=>x.Value>1).FirstOrDefault();
                    if((FirstOrDefault.Key==0 && FirstOrDefault.Value==0) ==false)
                    {
                        dictionary[FirstOrDefault.Key] = FirstOrDefault.Value-1;
                        dictionary.Add(array2[i], 1);
                        maxElementsToBeReplaced--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return dictionary.Select(x=>x.Key).Count();
    }
}
```